# Correctly implementing a custom QWidget in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm completely new to Qt/GUI programming and I'm trying to create the UI for a simple Tic Tac Toe game. I created two custom `QWidget` classes. My main window class (`GameWindow`) extends the base `QWidget`, and my other class `XOSpace` extends `QFrame`. `XOSpace` serves two purposes: dividing up the board into spaces (each one will have a `HLine` or `VLine` shape), and being a starting point for drawing X's and O's in the correct spot on the board (as soon as I can figure out how to use Qt painters and paint events). My problem is that when I add the `XOSpace`s to `GameWindow` they don't display. But when I added `QFrame` objects from the base class as a test, they displayed fine. How do I extend `QFrame` (or any widget class), and still make sure it will function the same as the base classes in Qt? Are there any functions I need to reimplement? Anything else?

```
class XOSpace : public QFrame {
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    XO xo ; //enum representing whether this space holds an X, O, or blank

public:
    explicit XOSpace(QWidget *parent = 0) ;
    explicit XOSpace(QWidget *parent, int size, QFrame::Shape) ;
    ~XOSpace();
    void setXO(XO) ;
};

XOSpace::XOSpace(QWidget *parent) : QFrame(parent) {
    this->xo = XO::blank ;
    this->setGeometry(QRect());
    this->setFrameShape(QFrame::HLine) ;
    this->setFrameShadow(QFrame::Sunken) ;
    this->setMinimumWidth(96) ;
    this->setLineWidth(1) ;
    this->show();
}

XOSpace::XOSpace(QWidget* parent, int size, QFrame::Shape shape) : QFrame(parent) {
    this->xo = XO::blank ;
    this->setGeometry(QRect());
    this->setFrameShape(shape);
    this->setFrameShadow(QFrame::Sunken);
    this->setMinimumWidth(size) ;
    this->setLineWidth(1) ;
    this->show() ;
}

QSize XOSpace::sizeHint() const {
    return this->size();
}

void XOSpace::setXO(XO xo) {
    this->xo = xo ;
}

XOSpace::~XOSpace() {
   ;
}



namespace Ui {
    class GameWindow;
}

class GameWindow : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    Ui::GameWindow *ui ;

    //these don't display:
    vector<XOSpace*>* hSpaces ;

    //these do:
    QFrame* vLineOne ;
    /* declare 7 more
    like this */

public:
    explicit GameWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~GameWindow();
    friend class XOSpace ;
};

GameWindow::GameWindow(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent),    
        ui(new Ui::GameWindow) {

    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setWindowTitle("Hello world!");

    QGridLayout *mainLayout = new QGridLayout() ;
    mainLayout->setColumnMinimumWidth(0, 25); 
    mainLayout->setColumnMinimumWidth(6, 25);

    this->setLayout(mainLayout) ;

    QPushButton* button = new QPushButton("Play") ;
    button->setFixedWidth(100);
    mainLayout->addWidget(button, 2, 3) ;

    QGridLayout* secondaryLayout = new QGridLayout() ;
    mainLayout->addLayout(secondaryLayout, 1, 1, 1, 5); 

    QGroupBox* gBox = new QGroupBox() ;
    secondaryLayout->addWidget(gBox, 0, 0);

    QGridLayout* boardLayout = new QGridLayout() ;
    gBox->setLayout(boardLayout);

    hSpaces = new vector<XOSpace*>() ;


    vLineOne = new QFrame() ;
    vLineOne->setGeometry(QRect());
    vLineOne->setFrameShape(QFrame::VLine);
    vLineOne->setFrameShadow(QFrame::Sunken);
    vLineOne->setMinimumHeight(96) ;
    /*repeat for vLines 2-4
     */

    vLineFive = new QFrame() ;
    vLineFive->setGeometry(QRect());
    vLineFive->setFrameShape(QFrame::VLine);
    vLineFive->setFrameShadow(QFrame::Sunken);
    vLineFive->setMinimumHeight(48);
    /*repeat for vLines 6-8
     */

    for(vector<XOSpace*>::size_type i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++) {
       hSpaces->push_back(new XOSpace(this, 96,  
           QFrame::HLine));
    }

    //horizontal spaces: (don’t display properly)
    boardLayout->addWidget(hSpaces->at(0), 0, 0,  
        Qt::AlignBottom);
    boardLayout->addWidget(hSpaces->at(1), 0, 2, 
        Qt::AlignBottom);
    boardLayout->addWidget(hSpaces->at(2), 0, 4, 
        Qt::AlignBottom);
    boardLayout->addWidget(hSpaces->at(3), 3, 0, Qt::AlignTop);
    boardLayout->addWidget(hSpaces->at(4), 3, 2, Qt::AlignTop);
    boardLayout->addWidget(hSpaces->at(5), 3, 4, Qt::AlignTop);

    //vertical spaces:  (display OK)
    boardLayout->addWidget(vLineOne, 0, 1) ;
    boardLayout->addWidget(vLineFive, 1, 1) ;
    boardLayout->addWidget(vLineTwo, 0, 3) ;
    boardLayout->addWidget(vLineSix, 1, 3) ;
    boardLayout->addWidget(vLineThree, 2, 1) ;
    boardLayout->addWidget(vLineSeven, 3, 1) ;
    boardLayout->addWidget(vLineFour, 2, 3) ;
    boardLayout->addWidget(vLineEight, 3, 3) ;


    mainLayout->setRowStretch(0, 1);
    //set rows and columns stretch

    mainLayout->setVerticalSpacing(0) ;
    //set spacing etc.

}

GameWindow::~GameWindow() {
    delete ui;
    if (hSpaces != nullptr) {
        for(vector<XOSpace*>::size_type i = 0 ; i < hSpaces->size() ; i++) {
            if (hSpaces->at(i) != nullptr) {
                delete hSpaces->at(i) ;
            }
        }
        delete hSpaces ;
    }
}
```

---

The `XOSpace`s are supposed to be drawn as horizontal line segments that will make up the two horizontal lines on a tic tac toe board. Here's what my application looks like now:
[image]

Comment: Don't call `show()` yourself in the ctor - the user of the class should do that. `setGeometry(QRect())` also doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a lot of little pieces of advice.  The first GUI or two that you make in Qt will probably be pretty hard to do.  Using layouts, like you have started doing will help quite a bit.

So here are the first couple recommendations I would give:

Don't call `show` in your `xospace` constructors.  Adding them to a layout, makes it the parent's job to show it.  So in your main when you call `gameWindow->show();` it handles all the showing of nested elements.

`QLabel` is a subclass of `QFrame`.  Change the elements in question to be of type `QLabel` and then add in `setText("X")` to their constructor or somewhere to make sure you can see your elements.

If you aren't using a the UI form, I would leave it out.

Based on your game layout, this is what your variables look like:

```
//      vL1     vL2
// hs0  vL6 hs1 vL5 hs2
//      vL3     vL4
// hs3  vL7 hs4 vL8 hs5
//      ???     ???
```

Instead of relying on the size of these vertical and horizontal lines for your stretching and size constraints, why not use the elements that will sit on the board, like in spots marked with an X below:

```
//  X   vL1  X  vL2  X
// hs0  vL6 hs1 vL5 hs2
//  X   vL3  X  vL4  X
// hs3  vL7 hs4 vL8 hs5
//  X   ???  X  ???  X
```

This would allow you to take two and span them across the grid.

```
boardLayout->addWidget(vLines.at(0), 0, 1, 5, 1) ;
boardLayout->addWidget(vLines.at(1), 0, 3, 5, 1) ;
mainLayout->setRowStretch(1, 1);
```

Then like I hint above, you could use a `QList` or a `QVector` to remove so much copy and paste code.

```
vLines.append(new QFrame);
vLines.append(new QFrame);

foreach(QFrame * f, vLines)
{
    //f->setGeometry(QRect());
    f->setFrameShape(QFrame::VLine);
    f->setFrameShadow(QFrame::Sunken);
    f->setMinimumHeight(96);
}
```

Also `setGeometry()` is useful if you aren't using layouts.  And setting the geometry to QRect(), is probably equivalent to the default constructor it has.

And when you start putting object trees together, you don't have to worry as much about how they clean up:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/objecttrees.html

EDIT:

Here is how I would layout the board:

```
QGridLayout * board = new QGridLayout();
for(int r = 0; r < 5; r++)
{
    for(int c = 0; c < 5; c++)
    {
        if(r % 2 == 1)
        {
            if(c % 2 == 1)
            {
                // is an intersection
                // leave it blank?
                // or add a box?
            }
            else
            {
                // is a horizontal line
                QFrame * f = new QFrame();
                f->setFrameShape(QFrame::HLine);
                f->setFrameShadow(QFrame::Sunken);
                f->setMinimumWidth(96);
                board->addWidget(f,r, c);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(c % 2 == 1)
            {
                // is a vertical line
                QFrame * f = new QFrame();
                f->setFrameShape(QFrame::VLine);
                f->setFrameShadow(QFrame::Sunken);
                f->setMinimumHeight(96);
                board->addWidget(f, r, c);
            }
            else
            {
                // is an XO location
                board->addWidget(new QLabel(), r, c, Qt::AlignCenter);
            }
        }
    }
}
setLayout(board);
```

Then if you just let `QGridLayout` manage your item's location and access, you do something like this:

```
void GameWindow::setXO(QString val, int r, int c)
{
    // upper left xo location is 0,0
    // lower right xo location is 2,2
    // we map to skip the frame locations
    if(r > 2 || r < 0 || c < 0 || c > 2)
    {
        qDebug() << "Error in setXO" << r << c;
        return;
    }

    QLabel * xo = qobject_cast<QLabel*>(board->itemAtPosition(r*2, c*2)->widget());
    if(xo != 0)
    {
        xo->setText(val);
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This was very helpful. Your suggestion to use `for` loops in setting up the board is a good one.