# Qt Dynamic QLabel creation

Tags: qt, dynamic

I need create and add to grid layout 8 Labels:

```
QLabel *cell[9];
for(int i=0;i<9;i++) {
    cell[i] = new QLabel(this);
    ui->gridLayout->addWidget(cell[i]);
}
```

but QtCreator writes

```
Error - RtlWerpReportException failed with status code :-1073741823. Will try to launch the process directly
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Do you need to keep track of the labels (do you need to store your label array)?

Comment: What is that inside of?  IE, what is "this"?  If you remove "this" from the `QLabel` constructor does it work?  If `this` isn't a QObject then the above will fail, certainly.

Comment: yes, i need keep track of the labels

Answer (score 0):

I would let the grid layout manage access to your `QLabel`s.  Check out the example in the link.

[Correctly implementing a custom QWidget in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20164347/correctly-implementing-a-custom-qwidget-in-qt/20166225#20166225)

Note towards the end of that answer, how to access a widget from a grid layout:

```
QLabel * label = qobject_cast<QLabel*>(m_gridLayout->itemAtPosition(row, col)->widget());
if(label != 0)
{
    label->setText(val);
}
```

Hope that helps.